Need help identifying the name of this crime movie or TV show
I have a very detailed memory of when I was about 6 to 10 years old.
My mom and aunt were watching an American (or at least English language) thriller/crime movie, and I have remembered it even since then (I'm 22 now). So the movie seemed relatively new because they watched it at different times as if it was on the TV a lot. Let's say the earliest is came out was 1994 when I was born just for the hell of it. However it could have been earlier or later.  This is what remember about this movie. 

A very good looking young guy (white with dark hair) who attracted a girl (blonde) who I believe had glasses. She was kind of nerdy looking but liked him a lot mostly because he was very handsome. He befriended her to get her to like him but ultimately killed her. This was not a big name actress. See photo for idea. 
A very specific scene of the guy cornering her in some sort of old abandoned warehouse/barn with a cooling fan in the wall behind her. They were up on a catwalk or beam of some sort and she was clearly scared of him and backing up into the wall behind her. 
A scene of her being found dead, wrapped in a white sheet or shower curtain, in the daylight in the middle of a field by a dirt road. I seem to remember there were bleach bottles around her and she was found by a cop. The cop was older around 50s and on the heavier side. He wore a brown sheriff style hat. It was obvious that the guy killed her. 

It could also be a crime show. I know it's a long shot and I've looked up so many movies and shows and it's never the one. 
I know I don't have any actor names or specifics at all but who knows, maybe someone knows what I'm talking about.
*Photos are similar to what I remember!


Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. ? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title
